# Extending inheritance of `this` to methods / properties of an `object`

Tags: javascript, inheritance, methods, this

I'm not sure if I phrased the question title correctly; please consider the following to clarify...

```
(function() {
    var foo = {
        bar: function() {
            // Is it possible to reference 'this' as the
            // initializing 'object' aka 'e' and not 'foo' ?
            // The easy part, currently because 'this' refers to 'foo',
            // is returning 'this' aka 'foo' so that chaining can occur
            return this;
        },
        other: function() {
            return this;
        }
    };
    Event.prototype.foo = foo; 
}());

// usage
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e.foo.bar().other();
};
```

How would I go about having access to `this` within the methods / props of `foo` but having `this` refer to the initial `object` aka `e` and not `foo` ?

---

The best that I have come up with is this

```
(function() {
    var foo = function() {
        var _foo = this.foo;
        _foo._this = this; //recursive reference that I am VERY worried about
        return _foo;
    };
    foo.bar = function() {
        var _this = this._this; //_this refers to initial 'object', 'e'
        return this; //return 'foo' aka 'this' for function chaining
    };
    foo.other = function() {
        var _this = this._this;
        return this;
    };
    Event.prototype.foo = foo; 
}());

// usage
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e.foo().bar().other();
};
```

---

What I have currently works but I am worried about a couple of things...
1. The recursive reference of assigning `e` to `e.foo._this`
and
2. The redundancy of assigning `e` to `e.foo._this`, if `this` could be accessed as `e` instead of `foo` it would make 'things' more performant, especially in regards to something like a mousemove event.

[jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ75m/2/)

---

Also, Im trying to avoid something like this...

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e.foo.bar.call(e);
};
```

---

All suggestions are appreciated, Thanks for your time.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly you basically want to access both, the `foo` object and the element that triggered the event?

Comment: @basilikum     Yes... kinda? The `event` itself and the `foo` object. Kinda like `this` and `this.foo`. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a subtle change to what you have you can make things simpler:

```
(function() {
    var foo = function() {
      this.foo.event = this;
      return this.foo;
    };
    foo.bar = function() {
      /// the event can be found in this.event
      return this;
    };
    foo.other = function() {
      /// the event can be found in this.event
      return this;
    };
    Event.prototype.foo = foo;
}());

// usage
document.onmousedown = function(e) {
    e.foo().bar().other();
};
```

This however is making a change to the shared object `foo`, you may wish to rewrite things so that `e.foo()` returns a new instance of `foo` instead, and move your other methods to `foo's` prototype.

```
(function() {
    var foo = function(event) {
      this.event = event;
    };
    foo.prototype.bar = function() {
      /// the event can be found in this.event
      return this;
    };
    foo.prototype.other = function() {
      /// the event can be found in this.event
      return this;
    };
    Event.prototype.foo = function() {
      return new foo(this);
    };
}());
```

This way you are creating a new instance of `foo` each time, but it means your addition of the `event` property is localised to that instance; the prototyped methods will be shared across all instances so it's not too bad from an optimisational point of view.

Comment: @Terry No worries. There are always numerous ways to approach a solution in JavaScript, it's the reason why I like it so much as a language ;)

Comment: *nods head vigorously in agreement*. Perhaps it's the 'novelty' effect still in full blossom, because I'm still new to JS, but I don't think so. It's a very expressive language and I love learning it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that would work for you:

Use the `apply` method to change the `this` context in the called method and use `this.foo` to refer to `foo`:

```
(function () {
    var foo = function () {
        console.log(this);
        return this.foo;
    };
    foo.bar = function () {
        console.log(this);
        return this.foo;
    };
    foo.other = function () {
        console.log(this);
        return this.foo;
    };
    Event.prototype.foo = foo;
}());

// usage
document.onclick = function (e) {
    console.log(
        e.foo.apply(e).bar.apply(e).other.apply(e)
    );
};
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ75m/5/)**

Comment: +1 vote. I know beggars shouldn't be choosers but I was hoping to achieve something more inclusive (if that's the right word?) then multiple `call` or `apply` calls. Regardless, still awesome, Thanks basilikum ^_^

Comment: Thanks! :) Well, pebbl's solution does exactly that. A very nice way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be simpler to bind your function to its object :

```
someElement.onEvent = myObject.myHandlerFunction.bind(myObject);
```

so when this function will be called, its 'this' will be myObject.

Then you can make use of e.target to access the element.